# How do I require a file from inside a directory with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, require

I think I'm missing something here.  I have a directory like this:

```
myapp
|-lib
  |-package1
    |-dostuff.rb
  |-package2
    |-dostuff.rb
```

From an `irb` console I'm trying to test the library before I add it to my real project (a Rails app).  However, typing this:

```
require 'lib/package1/dostuff'
```

returns an error saying it can't find the file to load.  I added the lib directory to the load path but I'm not able to load the file.

What am I forgetting?  The two filenames don't have to be the same but that's how they are to begin with (they are auto-generated from some web services I need to call using soap4r; each package represents a different web service API group)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the directory "lib" is in the load path, the argument to require must be relative to lib. So `require 'package1/dostuff'` without the lib, otherwise it will look for `lib/lib/package1/dostuff.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 1.9 there's the new require_relative method, which would let you do `require_relative "../package2/dostuff"` from within `package1/dostuff.rb`.